# Overwrite when uploading files with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, overriding

i upload files in rails with following code:

```
name = upload['datafile'].original_filename
directory = "public/data/#{id}/#{app_id}"

Dir.mkdir("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{id}/#{app_id}")

path = File.join(directory, name)

File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
```

can someone tell me how i can tell rails, that it should overwrite the file when it already exists?

thanks!

Comment: Is this code not working for you?  Is there an error?

Comment: this code works, but i get an error "file exists" when o upload something twice.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if a dir already exist:

```
name = upload['datafile'].original_filename
directory = "public/data/#{id}/#{app_id}"

Dir.mkdir("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{id}/#{app_id}") unless Dir.exist? "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/data/#{id}/#{app_id}"

path = File.join(directory, name)

File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
```

Comment: This answer is correct. The explanation is: The error `Errno::EEXIST: File exists` will occur when you try to create a *directory* that already exists, so checking if the directory already exists should prevent the error.